# Django createsuperuser not working due to TTY error

Tags: python, django, anaconda, superuser

In django after populating the database, I started superuser creation but it fails and shows the error. Since I'm new to django and I cannot understand what is the error is about?

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

**Error:**

```
Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. 
You can run `manage.py createsuperuser` in your project to create one manually.
```

Comment: May be [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for) would help you better understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command inside a terminal with the path to manage.py as your working directory.

Comment: I'm using anaconda and I run it in conda's terminal which is same as cmd prompt